# How to vertically center canvas with phaser.io?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've a responsive game with the phaser library and I configured its canvas to horizontally and vertically center in the page with these lines:

```
game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
```

Though it's not vertically centered – only horizontally centered. Is there another way to vertically align the game from phaser, but in the center of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not another way, but I finally got why it wasn't vertically centering the game. The frame element for the phaser game must have full width and full height, or can be simply the `body` with a specific id. I was thinking phaser would do that already.

I found the [idea](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/13874-pagealignvertically/) after centuries. I should have displayed my CSS code in the question, so I'm sorry.